# C++かObjective-cでByte配列からByte配列にZip解凍したい

Tags: objective-c, c#, c++

C#側でtarからZipをMemoryStreamに取り出すことができたので、
これをiOS側に渡してC++かobejective-cでunzipして、
unzipしたものをbyte配列もしくはStreamで持ちたいのですが、
C++かobejective-cでZipのByte配列をUnZipしてByte配列に変換する方法、
もしくはライブラリはないでしょうか？

まだObejective-c側しか調査してないのですが、
SSZipArchiveやObjectiveZipというものを見つけたのですが
ファイル名を与えないと解凍できないようでして、
C#のZipInputStreamのようなものがなく悩んでおります。

●SSZipArchive
https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive
●ObjectiveZip
https://github.com/gianlucabertani/Objective-Zip

■追記(Zlib 使用)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <zlib.h>


extern "C"{
    void uncompressByGzip(const char** ptrSrc, const int srcLength);
}


void uncompressByGzip(const char** ptrSrc, const int srcLength)
{
    NSData *source = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)ptrSrc length:(sizeof(unsigned char) * srcLength)];

    NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",srcLength];
    NSLog(@"src = %@",str);
    if (source.length == 0)
        return;
    NSLog(@"11111");

    z_stream stream;
    stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    stream.opaque = Z_NULL;
    stream.avail_in = (uInt)source.length;
    stream.next_in = (Bytef *)source.bytes;
    stream.total_out = 0;
    stream.avail_out = 0;

    NSLog(@"22222");
    if (inflateInit2(&stream, 31) != Z_OK)
        return;

    NSLog(@"33333");
    NSMutableData *FileSystemData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];
    while (stream.avail_out == 0) {
        NSLog(@"12345");
        Bytef buffer[16384];
        stream.next_out = buffer;
        stream.avail_out = sizeof(buffer);
        NSString* avail_outbef = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(NSInteger)stream.avail_out];
        NSLog(@"avail_outbef = %@",avail_outbef);

//        inflate(&stream, Z_FINISH);
        inflate(&stream,Z_NO_FLUSH);
        size_t length = sizeof(buffer) - stream.avail_out;

        avail_outbef = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(NSInteger)stream.avail_out];
        NSLog(@"avail_outaft = %@",avail_outbef);

        NSString* strlength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(NSInteger)length];
        NSLog(@"length = %@",strlength);

        if (length > 0)
            [FileSystemData appendBytes:buffer length:length];
    }
    inflateEnd(&stream);
    NSLog(@"44444");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSZipArchiveもObjectiveZipも[Minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html)のラッパーなので、Minizipをそのまま使ったほうがいいと思います。
MiniZipを直接使えばファイルを介さずにメモリから読み書きできます。

Comment: 使い方についての質問です、Minizipのioapi_mem.c にあるfopen_mem_funcのFilenameのコメントに<hex base of zip file>+<hex size of zip file>　とあるのですが、sprintf(opaque, "%x %x", Zipファイルのbyte配列の先頭アドレスを16進変換, Zipファイルのbyte配列のサイズ);　を渡せばいいのでしょうか？

Comment: そのバージョンのAPIはわかりにくいので[github](https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip)にあるものを使ったほうがいいと思います。

Comment: なるほど、使い方が非常に難しいです。サンプルもほとんどヒットしないので解析してみます。

Answer (score 2):

c のライブラリですが zlib はどうでしょうか？
`inflate` 関数を使用すれば Stream で行うことができます。

xcode のプロジェクトには `Linked Frameworks And Libraries` から `libz` (ややこしい）で追加できます。

公式のサンプルは http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html
また日本語での解説は以下がわかりやすいと思います。 http://s-yata.jp/docs/zlib/

Comment: すいません、わからないことがあるのですが、出力先はz_streamになるのでしょうか？　質問に追記してコードを記載しました。　出力先バッファは解凍されると大きくなる必要があると思うのですが、それをどこでやってるのかがわからず。　サンプルを探しています。

Comment: zlib単体ではzipアーカイブの解凍はできません。